# What is the function of this circuit board in my office?

Tags: pcb, sensor, identification

I am renting a office in Sydney and in the office a sensor is installed.

Would like to know the function of it and how it works?

Is it possible to know that from the PCB design?

My guess is that it's a room temperature sensor.

I have attached the image of PCB here.

[image]

3 pin device has LM35DZ written on it with N79AL or just 79AL.

Comment: What's with the black square? If you're hiding the manufacturer's name or something, that's useful information that could indicate what the function is.

Comment: @ThePhoton manufacturer is OZTECH. It has OZTECH name there in black square and nothing else.

Comment: why do you need to know/:?

Comment: The black thing is the active temperature sensor in deg C/mV

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 i would like to know how to fool it to think it's colder then it is. It is installed in wrong place in the office. It's making my area very cold.

Comment: Being a digital thermal sensor, all you need is an ice cube not for you but near the sensor.

Answer (score 2):

Check the marking on the three-pin component near the PCB marking TS1. Given the very few components on the board and the 3-wires connection, I bet it's marked DS18B20. That's a remote temperature sensor chip.

Comment: Lots of 3-pin TO-92 temperature sensors out there. LMT85, 86, and 87 are three other ones.

Comment: None of these can be directly attached to a room wiring installation because you don't know its voltage drop.

Comment: @Janka no marking near three-pin component. I have attached the image.

Comment: The marking is on the flat side of the component.

Comment: @Janka no marking there as well. May be too small.

Comment: @janka 3 pin device is LM35DZ

Comment: Ah, very cheap, but indeed a temperature sensor.

Answer (score 1):

Based on you getting the part number, it is a National Semi LM35 analog centigrade temperature sensor. It should output 10 millivolt or 0.01 Volts per degree.

Since you want to lower it's temperature, foil would not work much. You could add a fan blowing on it. Or you can adjust it's voltage output. A simple voltage divider would work. A resistor voltage divider works on ratio, so a 1/10 ratio would help bring the voltage down by 10%. At 30 degrees that means the sensor thinks it's 27 degrees.

Or just complain to your facilities manager. If they have a per section control they can set your room to a higher temperature.

Comment: I am not electrical engineer. I get what you meant by voltage divider but how can it be done?

Comment: @MikeRoss well this is a site for electrical engineers so...